# Services for dummy outlook email addresses?

Tags: email, outlook

I'm currently testing multiple user profiles for a new system.

These users will all be using outlook.com, and an outlook plugin.

I need to test about 5 different profiles/addresses for outlook.com. I've been barred from creating more accounts.

What is your solution when testing multiple email profiles/accounts, where a few developers would need access.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to create Microsoft aliases and use mailbox filtering for my testing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/12407/microsoft-account-manage-aliases